# Import local SPM Library in local SPM package

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dependencies, swift-package-manager

I have a local SPM package that contains 2 libraries, and I want to import one of those libraries in another local SPM package :
**File containing the libraries:**

```
let package = Package(
    name: "LocationService",
    platforms: [.iOS(.v13)],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "LocationService",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["LocationService"]),
        .library(
          name: "LocationLiveClient",
          type: .dynamic,
          targets: ["LocationLiveClient"]),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "LocationService",
            dependencies: []),
        .target(
            name: "LocationLiveClient",
            dependencies: ["LocationService"],
            path: "Sources/LocationLiveClient"),
    ]
)
```

**File importing the libraries:**

```
let package = Package(
    name: "HomePage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "HomePage",
            type: .dynamic,
            targets: ["HomePage"])
    ],
    dependencies: [
      .package(path: "../RouterService"),
      .package(path: "../LocationService/Sources/LocationLiveClient"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "HomePage",
            dependencies: ["RouterService", "LocationLiveClient"])
    ]
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of issues to resolve here.

*(If a requirement of your design is to use 'dynamic' linking, then this approach may not work for you.)*

- `type: .dynamic`:

Unless you absolutely need to guarantee how library linking is achieved, it is recommended that you leave this as the default value of `nil` (just remove the line). This allows the swift package manager to determine how to best link the libraries (the default being 'static').

- `.package(path: "../LocationService/Sources/LocationLiveClient"),`

`LocationLiveClient` is a product & target of the `LocationService` package. In the dependencies here, a reference to the package as a whole should be made. So change this to `.package(path: "../LocationService"),`

- `dependencies: ["RouterService", "LocationLiveClient"])`

Once the change to depend on the whole location service package, the compiler needs a little extra information. You can update your target dependencies to specifically use the `LocationLiveClient` library in the `LocationService` package: `.product(name: "LocationLiveClient", package: "LocationService")`.

With those changes in place you end up with a Package definition like this:

```swift
let package = Package(
    name: "HomePage",
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "HomePage",
            targets: ["HomePage"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(path: "../RouterService"),
        .package(path: "../LocationService"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "HomePage",
            dependencies: [
                "RouterService",
                .product(name: "LocationLiveClient", package: "LocationService")
            ]
        ),
    ]
)
```

You should then be able to `import LocationLiveClient` as expected.

---

Side note: Assuming your 'LocationService' package has the following folder structure, then you can safely remove `path: "Sources/LocationLiveClient"` from your `LocationLiveClient` target definition.

```
LocationService
-> Sources
  -> LocationService
  -> LocationLiveClient
```

Comment: Thank you :) it worked, I was missing the fact that I can add the whole product as a dependency.